# SQLAlchemy database record created on import of module

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a model class `FlagTabel`:

```py
class FlagTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "FLAG_TABLE"

    FLAG_TABLE_ID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement="auto")
    COLUMN_1 = Column(Boolean)
    COLUMN_2 = Column(Boolean)
    COLUMN_3 = Column(Boolean)
```

I have a function in `FlagTable.py` that would create a record with the `FlagTable` object:

```py
from FlagTable import FlagTable

def addFlagsToFlagTable(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    myFlags = FlagTable(COLUMN_1=arg1, COLUMN_2=arg1, COLUMN_3=arg1)
    session.add(myFlags)
    session.commit()

#main code
callFunc = addFlagsToFlagTable(true, false, false)
```

When I step through the code in debugger mode I see that the record I want to add to my postgres database table gets added at the time of the import. It does not even wait for when the addFlagsToFlagTable function gets called in my main code. My *'Base = declarative_base()'* statement is in another class which is related to `FlagTable` class.

Comment: The line marked with `#main code` in which file is that line and how does that file look (redacted with what's required)?

Comment: Everything at module level is run when the module is evaluated during import. Perhaps you're looking for [What does `if __name__ == "__main__":` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: @rfkortekaas: the main code is in the same file as FlagTable.py. It is below the function definition.

Comment: @IljaEverilä: I am looking into this some more. Thank you for pointing this out to me.

Comment: Than the answer of Ilja is wat you need!